# PHP operator |= explain

Tags: php, operator-keyword

I have a code like this

```
<?php
$mask = 5;
$mask |= 10;
echo $mask;
?>
```

output of the above code is 15. But i cant understand the operator **|=**

Comment: `$mask |= 10;` means `$mask = $mask | 10;`

Comment: follow the below link http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$mask |= 10 means $mask = $mask | 10. '|' operator is called bitwise operator.
Follow the example how bitwise operator works.

```
$mask =$mask | 10
      = 5 | 10
Firstly we have to convert the decimal to binary.
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
               1 0 1 =>5
             1 0 1 0 => 10
So for 5| 10
Output will be 8+4+2+1 =15
```

Here we need to add all decimal number that is under 1 bit.

Another example For **10 | 10**

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
             1 0 1 0=>10
             1 0 1 0 => 10
```

So the result of **10 | 10** is

```
= 8+2 = 10
```

For more information visit this link
http://www.w3resource.com/php/operators/bitwise-operators.php